# C: Memory leak implementing a simple linked list

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, singly-linked-list

I created a linked list that stores integers. The program appears to run fine but Valgrind informs me that there is a memory leak.  I am not sure how this is possible.  The code is provided below along with the output and Valgrinds assesment.  Thank you.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "linked_list.h"

int main( int argc, char* argv[ ] ){
    int num = 0;
    NODE head = NULL;

    num = 7;

    head = list_insert( head, num );
    bytes_of_list( head );

    head = list_insert( head, 9 );
    bytes_of_list( head );

    head = list_insert( head, 2 );
    bytes_of_list( head );

    head = list_insert( head, 8 );
    bytes_of_list( head );

    delete_node( head, 6 );
    delete_node( head, 9 );
    bytes_of_list( head );

    print_list( head );
    printf( "\n" );

    linked_list_destroy( &head );
    bytes_of_list( head );

    return 0;
}
```

**linked_list.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "linked_list.h"
#include "status.h"

struct node;
typedef struct node Node;
struct node{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};
typedef struct node Node;

/************************************************************** list insert */
NODE list_insert( NODE head, int data ){
    Node* pNode = NULL;

    printf( "\nInsert %d into list.\n", data );

    pNode = ( Node* )malloc( sizeof( Node ));
    if( !pNode ) exit( 1 );
    pNode->data = data;
    pNode->next = head;
    return pNode;
}
/******************************************************  linked_list_destroy */
void linked_list_destroy( NODE* head ){
    Node* phead = ( Node* )*head;
    Node* prevNode = NULL;

    printf( "\nDestroy List:\n");

    if( !phead ) return;
    while( phead != NULL ){
        prevNode = phead;
        phead = phead->next;
        printf( "Deleting %d\n", prevNode->data );
        prevNode->data = 0;
        prevNode->next = NULL;
        free( prevNode );
    }
    *head = NULL;
}
/***************************************************************  print_list */
void print_list( NODE head ){
    Node* pHead = ( Node* )head;

    printf( "\nPrint list:\n");

    while( pHead != NULL ){
        printf( "%d ", pHead->data );
        pHead = pHead->next;
    }
}
/***********************************************************  delete nodes */
void delete_node( NODE head, int data ){
    Node* phead = ( Node* )head;
    Node* prev = NULL;

    printf( "\nDelete %d from list:\n", data );

    if( !head ) return;
    while(( phead != NULL ) && ( phead->data != data )){
        prev = phead;
        phead = phead->next;
    }
    if( !phead ) printf( "Sorry, %d is not in the list.\n", data);
    else{
        prev->next = phead->next;
        free( phead );
    }
    return;
}
/********************************************************* bytes of list */
int bytes_of_list( NODE head ){
    Node* phead = ( Node* )head;
    int bytes_total = 0;
    while( phead != NULL ){
        bytes_total += sizeof( *phead );
        phead = phead->next;
    }
    printf( "The current size of the list is %d bytes.\n", bytes_total );
    return bytes_total;
}
```

**linked_list.h**

```
#ifndef LINKED_LIST_H_INCLUDED
#define LINKED_LIST_H_INCLUDED
#include "status.h"

typedef void* NODE;
NODE list_insert( NODE head, int data );
void print_list( NODE head );
void linked_list_destroy( NODE* head );
void delete_node( NODE head, int data );
Status in_list( NODE head, int data );
int bytes_of_list( NODE head );

#endif
```

**status.h**

```
#ifndef STATUS_H_INCLUDED
#define STATUS_H_INCLUDED
enum status {FALSE, TRUE};
typedef enum status Status;
#endif
```

**Output for this program is as follows:**

Insert 7 into list.

The current size of the list is 16 bytes.

Insert 9 into list.

The current size of the list is 32 bytes.

Insert 2 into list.

The current size of the list is 48 bytes.

Insert 8 into list.

The current size of the list is 64 bytes.

Delete 6 from list:

Sorry, 6 is not in the list.

Delete 9 from list:

The current size of the list is 48 bytes.

Print list:

8 2 7

Destroy List:

Deleting 8

Deleting 2

Deleting 7

The current size of the list is 0 bytes.

**VALGRIND OUTPUT:**

==2758== HEAP SUMMARY:

==2758==     in use at exit: 140,089 bytes in 1,198 blocks

==2758==   total heap usage: 1,968 allocs, 770 frees, 283,758 bytes allocated

==2758==

==2758== LEAK SUMMARY:

==2758==    definitely lost: 10 bytes in 1 blocks

==2758==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==2758==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==2758==    still reachable: 140,079 bytes in 1,197 blocks

==2758==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==2758== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory

==2758==

==2758== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v

==2758== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

Comment: I'd advise rerunning it with `--leak-check=full` as the output log suggests to see further details.

Comment: When I run this in `valgrind` v3.13.0, I get: `All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible`.  Maybe upgrade your Valgrind.

Comment: I tried:  valgrind -v --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all  make run
 and it appears that there is a re-occurring leak that starts out at 1 byte in loss record 1/219 and seems to snowball into larger amounts ending at 65,536 bytes in loss record 219/219... i

Comment: I will try to upgrade Valgrind and see what happens. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: OT: regarding: `int main( int argc, char* argv[ ] ){`   When the parameters to `main()` are not used, then use the signature `int main( void )`

Comment: OT: regarding: `pNode = ( Node* )malloc( sizeof( Node ));` in C, the returned type from any of the heap allocation functions is :`void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: regarding: `if( !pNode ) exit( 1 );` for ease of readability and understanding: follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*.  Also, the user should be informed of this error.  Suggest inserting: `perror( "malloc failed" );`  before the call to `exit()`

Comment: this convolution: `struct node;
typedef struct node Node;
struct node{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};
typedef struct node Node;`  should be written as: `struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node Node;`

Comment: I removed Valgrind from my machine and reinstalled v3.14.  I also changed main( int argc, char* arg[ ] ); to main( );  but I am still getting the same memory leaks.  I am going to try it on another machine to see what happens... Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: regarding the function: `void delete_node( Node *head, int data )`  When the node to delete is the first node then this function will fail.  Suggest passing a `Node **head` then modifying the code to allow for that change.  Otherwise cannot delete the first Node

Comment: the operator: `sizeof` returns a `size_t`, so the function `bytes_of_list()` (and calls to that function) need to be modified to use `size_t` rather than `int`

Comment: the function: `main()` contains lots of calls to function: `bytes_of_list()` but never uses the returned value.  Suggest changing the return type to `void`  I.E. `void bytes_of_list( Node* head )`

Comment: the function: `list_insert()`, if `malloc` fails, just exits.  Before exiting, it should call: `linked_list_destroy()` to pass the many heap allocated memory areas to `free()`.  However that function contains the statement: `*head = NULL;` which will only modify the copy of the pointer on the call stack and not the initial variable in `main()`  Suggest either passing `Node **head`  and modifying the code accordingly or (less desirable) removing that statement.  similar considerations exist for the function: `delete_node()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version of the posted code

1. all jammed into a single file
2. with all the suggested fixes:
3. that cleanly compiles
4. that informs the user when an error occurs

And now, the proposed version of the code:

```
#ifndef STATUS_H_INCLUDED
#define STATUS_H_INCLUDED
enum status {FALSE, TRUE};
typedef enum status Status;
#endif



#ifndef LINKED_LIST_H_INCLUDED
#define LINKED_LIST_H_INCLUDED
//include "status.h"
#include <stdio.h>

struct node 
{ 
    int data; 
    struct node *next; 
}; 
typedef struct node Node;

Node* list_insert( Node *head, int data );
void print_list( Node *head );
void linked_list_destroy( Node** head );
void delete_node( Node** head, int data );
Status in_list( Node* head, int data );
void bytes_of_list( Node* head );

#endif


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include "linked_list.h"

int main( void )
{
    int num = 0;
    Node *head = NULL;

    num = 7;

    head = list_insert( head, num );
    bytes_of_list( head );

    head = list_insert( head, 9 );
    bytes_of_list( head );

    head = list_insert( head, 2 );
    bytes_of_list( head );

    head = list_insert( head, 8 );
    bytes_of_list( head );

    delete_node( &head, 6 );
    delete_node( &head, 9 );
    bytes_of_list( head );

    print_list( head );
    printf( "\n" );

    linked_list_destroy( &head );
    bytes_of_list( head );

    return 0;
}


//#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <stdio.h>
//#include "linked_list.h"
//#include "status.h"




/************************************************************** list insert */
Node *list_insert( Node *head, int data )
{
    printf( "\nInsert %d into list.\n", data );

    Node *pNode = malloc( sizeof( Node ));
    if( !pNode )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    pNode->data = data;
    pNode->next = head;
    return pNode;
}


/******************************************************  linked_list_destroy */
void linked_list_destroy( Node** head )
{
    Node* phead = *head;
    Node* prevNode = NULL;

    printf( "\nDestroy List:\n");


    while( phead )
    {
        prevNode = phead;
        phead = phead->next;
        printf( "Deleting %d\n", prevNode->data );
        prevNode->data = 0;
        prevNode->next = NULL;
        free( prevNode );
    }
    *head = NULL;
}


/***************************************************************  print_list */
void print_list( Node *head )
{
    Node* pHead = head;

    printf( "\nPrint list:\n");

    while( pHead )
    {
        printf( "%d ", pHead->data );
        pHead = pHead->next;
    }
}


/***********************************************************  delete nodes */
void delete_node( Node **head, int data )
{
    Node* phead = *head;
    Node* prev  = NULL;

    printf( "\nDelete %d from list:\n", data );

    //if( !head ) return;

    while(( phead ) && ( phead->data != data ))
    {
        prev = phead;
        phead = phead->next;
    }

    if( !phead ) 
    {
        printf( "Sorry, %d is not in the list.\n", data);
    }

    else
    {
        prev->next = phead->next;
        free( phead );
    }
    return;
}


/********************************************************* bytes of list */
void bytes_of_list( Node* head )
{
    Node* phead = head;
    size_t bytes_total = 0;

    while( phead )
    {
        bytes_total += sizeof( *phead );
        phead = phead->next;
    }

    printf( "The current size of the list is %lu bytes.\n", bytes_total );
    //return bytes_total;
}
```

Comment: Wow, great job!  I'm still unsure as to why I was getting memory leaks.  I'll have to examine your fixes in more detail tomorrow.  Thank you very much!

Comment: You were getting memory leaks because there was lots of allocated memory those pointers were never passed to `free()` during the process of deleting the whole list